# How to use php-5.6 from ppa:ondrej/php repository when using php-fpm?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.6, fpm

I was wordering if it's possible to install php-5.6 from ppa:ondrej/php repository within php-fpm. For now, i was using a tutorial that builds php from source: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/

How can i setup a similar configuration using the php-5.6 from ppa:ondrej/php?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question was answered indirectelly by ahrasis, here: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/install-intl-php-7-1-extension-in-a-php-multiple-version-server.75406/#post-356624

For FastCGI add something like:

```
Path to the PHP FastCGI binary = /usr/bin/php-cgi5.6

Path to the php.ini directory = /etc/php/5.6/cgi
```

For > PHP-FPM

```
Path to the PHP-FPM init script = /etc/init.d/php5.6-fpm

Path to the php.ini directory = /etc/php/5.6/fpm

Path to the PHP-FPM pool directory = /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d
```